# Installed ubuntu 18.04.4 desktop from a USB; "Missing Operating System"

Tags: boot, boot-repair

We have a HP Compaq 6000 pro which was purchased as a refurbished computer. We have been able to install Ubuntu and wipe off the old Windows 10, as desired. If we try to start the computer we get the message "Missing Operating System_". We can use the USB and get back on, but it repeatedly takes us to the boot menu. We have played around in there, changing the boot order mostly, but nothing is helping. We really do not know what we are doing, so we need very simple/clear explanations.

Answer (score 1):

So we asked my nephew to help us. As he was looking at the situation he had my husband go in and disable some security setting. Then everything worked fine. My husband has been using Ubuntu on his computer for about 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the installation did it detect that Windows was there and give you the option to Erase disk and install fresh or install alongside?  Without seeing screen shots of what is happening it is difficult to say for sure but it sounds like Ubuntu may not have been installed on the disk that the system is attempting to boot from.  You might try reinstalling again and make sure it is seeing the storage device you expect.  If it was installed there it should give you different options to install alongside, delete desk, etc.

Comment: It probably did give the option you mention on the first try, and my husband would have chosen erase disk. His intent is to have only Ubuntu on the computer hard drive.  We have tried multiple times to install Ubuntu again, and that option to install alongside no longer appears. The first series of times we tried Ubuntu 19.04; then we switched to 18.04. It seems like everything goes according to what the videos would have us expect. We think everything is fine, until we reboot the computer.

Comment: Hi Jean...cant say that I have seen that particular issue before.  You might try fiddling with the boot options in the BIOS/Setup screen.  Toggle between UEFI/BIOS/Legacy.  If the machine has the option to engage a temporary boot window try to select that and force it to boot from the hard drive.  And/or rearrange the boot order of devices to have the hard drive be the first one.  Sorry cant be of more help with this issue.  :(

Comment: We went in to look, and the files from the USB device did transfer to the hard drive. We noticed an X in the folder labelled "root"; when we clicked on properties it said it was unreadable.